# Fill background Color in the first cell of excel using Open XML C#

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am trying to fill background color in first cell of excel. Below is the code I am using to access the cell of the excel & fill color but its not working. Can somebody help me by telling me what am I doing wrong or is there any other way to do this?

below is the code that I am using for this part:

```
WorkbookPart workbookPart = myWorkbook.WorkbookPart;
                WorksheetPart worksheetPart = null;
                workbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.ForceFullCalculation = true;
                workbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.FullCalculationOnLoad = true;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sheetName))
                {
                    Sheet ss = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == sheetName).SingleOrDefault<Sheet>();
                    worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)workbookPart.GetPartById(ss.Id);
                }
                else
                {
                    worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.FirstOrDefault();
                }
                int cellIndex = 0;
                if (worksheetPart != null)
                {
                    SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();

            Row FirstRow = GetRow(worksheetPart.Worksheet, 0);


                    Cell cell1Legend = GetCell(worksheetPart.Worksheet, "A", 1);


                uint fillIndex = AddFillByColor(myWorkbook.WorkbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart, System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);

                    uint cellformatIndex = AddCellFormatWithFill(myWorkbook.WorkbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart, fillIndex);

                    CellAppendCellFormat(Cell1Legend, cellformatIndex);
```